# Windows' private network map for myself

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, network-shares

Is it possible to ***somehow*** set up a "private" network map just for myself in Windows?

I want to setup a network map into my own disk in Windows, on a common/shared machine, but don't want other people to see/access that network drive. Is it possible?

Reason being not all software can access networks share directly as `\\myhost\C$`, e.g., all tools under git-bash.

Comment: Mapped network drives are always "private" (-> user account specific). Even if you execute a command with admin permissions (UAC prompt) this is already a "different account" so your mapped drives created by your account without admin permission are not available.

Comment: I gave it a try @Robert, but unfortunately, when I mapped drives with my own account, then check with the CMD under admin permissions, I saw my mapped drives. Maybe even under admin permissions, I'm still using my own account?

Answer (score 1):

To prevent people from accessing it, grant read/write or even full control permissions only to your account and delete all other accounts from the ACL.

To prevent people from seeing it, you can make it a hidden share by adding `$` at the end of the name of the share. Windows will "respect" that and not showing that this share exists, but Linux doesn't care and would show others that it exists. But even if they knew its existance, they could not access it, because of your wisely configured access rights.